# How do I use windows programs on Ubuntu without wine

Tags: windows, wine, games

I have a game I want to play but it is only for windows and wine doesn't work for it. Is there a program besides wine that can do windows program on ubuntu?

Comment: Are you excluding VM's?

Comment: You could try magic. It does work for some.

Answer (score 3):

Honestly, you don't. Wine is the only good, updated program that runs Windows Programs. It is the best, and at the time, only solution to Microsoft not making their programs universal.